# Parsing XML attributes in PL/SQL query

Tags: xml, oracle

Please check for XML below in PL/SQL below and output should like this:

```
CITY_NAME   POPULATION
MUMBAI  6780000
DELHI   5100000
HYDERABAD   2480000
CHENNAI 6100000
```

I'm using the query below but is there a better way to handle instead of joining on **rownum**. I acknowledge that XML format could be better in handling XML attributes.

```
WITH t as (select XMLTYPE('
<ROOT>
    <CITY_INFO>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="MUMBAI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="6780000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="DELHI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="5100000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
    </CITY_INFO>
    <CITY_INFO>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="HYDERABAD"/>
          <POPULATION Value="2480000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="CHENNAI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="6100000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
    </CITY_INFO>
</ROOT>
') as xml from dual)
select a.CITY_NAME, b.population from (select c.*, rownum as row_num
from t
           ,XMLTABLE('/ROOT/CITY_INFO/CITY/CITY_NAME'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) PATH '/CITY_NAME/@Value'
             ) c) a,
             (select pop.*, rownum as row_num
             from t
           ,XMLTABLE('/ROOT/CITY_INFO/CITY/POPULATION'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS POPULATION NUMBER PATH '/POPULATION/@Value'
             ) pop) b where a.row_num = b.row_num
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or is your current output not what it "should" be? Add these details to your question. If your current output is different than add the current output.

Comment: The output from the query is same as expected but innerjoin on rownum didn't look clean. Answer posted below achieves the output without parsing twice and joining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing the "root path" in the xmltable to be the level before the `CITY_NAME` and `POPULATION` nodes, and referencing the `CITY_NAME` and `POPULATION` nodes via `//`, the following works for me:

```
WITH t as (select XMLTYPE('
<ROOT>
    <CITY_INFO>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="MUMBAI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="6780000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="DELHI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="5100000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
    </CITY_INFO>
    <CITY_INFO>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="HYDERABAD"/>
          <POPULATION Value="2480000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
        <CITY>
          <CITY_NAME Value="CHENNAI"/>
          <POPULATION Value="6100000" OldValue=""/>
        </CITY>
    </CITY_INFO>
</ROOT>
') as xml from dual)
select a.CITY_NAME, a.population 
from   t,
       XMLTABLE('/ROOT/CITY_INFO/CITY'
              PASSING t.xml
              COLUMNS CITY_NAME VARCHAR2(100) PATH '//CITY_NAME/@Value',
              POPULATION NUMBER PATH '//POPULATION/@Value'
             ) a;

CITY_NAME            POPULATION
-------------------- ----------
MUMBAI                  6780000
DELHI                   5100000
HYDERABAD               2480000
CHENNAI                 6100000
```

Comment: Thank you that works. Sorry can't vote up as I am a newb